# Не получается подключить библиотеку css к html

Tags: html, css

Не могу никак подключить библиотеку css к html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Читалкино</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Путь к файлу css: D:\Python\html\one\css

Comment: есть относительные и абсолютные пути, где лежит файл html а где css?

Comment: html находится здесь: D:\Python\html\one

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынуть css файл из папки так чтобы html и css были в одной папке, далее обычно присоедините их.

Comment: Не-а, всё равно не работает